# Angular MAT_DATE_FORMATS change values at runtime (FIXED)

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-date-format

So in my Module when I do the import of the Material date picker, i provide MAT_DATE_FORMATS

`{ provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: MAT_MOMENT_DATE_FORMATS }`

But the value to be provided is dependant on the user since the date format is a user setting. This implies that I need to be able to change the value of `MAT_DATE_FORMATS` at runtime. I already tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61364618/angular-date-picker-update-mat-date-formats-dynamically). In which in my user service listen to events

```
Class SomeUserService {
  constructor(@Inject(MAT_DATE_FORMATS) formats: MatDateFormats) {
      this.userSessionSubject.subscribe((s) => {
          formats.parse.dateInput = session.dateFormat;
          formats.display.dateInput = session.dateFormat;
     });
  }
}
```

So I thought that this would simply update the formats globally throught the app wherever I use a `<mat-datepicker>`. But this does not work. In my test case, the setted dateInput would be the string `'dd/MM/YYYY'` or `'DD/MM/YYYY'`; Yet a datepicker will still display the US notation in the input field.

[image]

This is how the DatePicker with input field is displayed

```
<mat-form-field class="w-100 no-border-mat-input">
  <input matInput [matDatepicker]="datePicker" placeholder="placeholder" formControlName="date" required="getRequired('date')" name="date">
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="datePicker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #datePicker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

**EDIT 1**

I also tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65780489/change-date-format-in-mat-datepicker-dynamically/65783137#65783137) as suggested in the comments and although my formatting is called, it is not applied in the datepicker nor the input field.

[image]
[image]

And in the screenshot below I list my providers (only one present which is to call the formatting)
[image]

**EDIT 2**

Fixed: I needed to import the `MatMomentDateModule` and it made everything work.

Comment: Can you try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51634726/how-to-change-angular-material-datepicker-format-in-run-time/51696436#51696436

Comment: So the idea there is to replace the provisioning of formats to do the formatting logic ourselves. We indeed had both but I sought to simplify it by globally setting it in a central place and have it available by default everywhere.

Comment: And the reason for it was simply this: suppose I enter the date March 2, 2022, then it will be formatted to 02/03/2022 (DD/MM/YYYY). But if change the year to 2021 then the date given to my service is Feburary 3 2021, so somewhere in the Angular/Material framework is was of that impression.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65780489/change-date-format-in-mat-datepicker-dynamically/65783137#65783137 ?

Comment: @Eliseo that answer is exactly what I need but for God knows what reason it won't work :(

Comment: See that the "key" is indicate the providers (you can give it in the module or in the component: `providers: [{provide: DateAdapter,useClass: CustomDateAdapter,deps: [MAT_DATE_LOCALE, MAT_MOMENT_DATE_ADAPTER_OPTIONS]},{ provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useClass: MyFormat }]`